# Is it possible to over ride the functionality provided by windows. When i hover my cursor over my app on task bar?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I am working on a small project. I would like to know whether i can override the functionality provided by Microsoft when i hover my cursor over an app on task bar? For example when I drop any file above my app in taskbar I want a list/My UI to be shown with options to do with the the file.

Comment: Can you be more specific here?

Comment: Override in which way? You can provide a custom preview image, jump-lists and buttons inside the preview with [these APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Override the ui which comes up..for example when i drop any file above my app in taskbar..i want a list/My UI to be shown [Options to do with the the file]..

Comment: No, you cannot customize drag/drop, PeterT listed the supported customizations.

Comment: What framework are you using? If you are using MFC, did you try implementing OnDropFiles handler for your taskbar. If you did, what was the problem with it? You can read about OnDropFiles handler here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62zys01d.aspx

Comment: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391704(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hi, to see all the available customization you can do in your app you can start from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx